# Can refresh tokens expire for GitLab OAuth?

Tags: oauth-2.0, gitlab, access-token, gitlab-api

The GitLab `access_token` has an expiry time of 2hours, similarly does the `refresh_token` also has some expiry time?

Because sometimes, when I use the `refresh_token` to get new `access_token` it throws `invalid_grant` error.

I am thinking `refresh_token` does not have any `expiry_time`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking refresh_token does not have any expiry_time

Indeed but they are linked to access_token.

In "**[Supporting Expiring OAuth Access Tokens for GitLab](https://northflank.com/blog/supporting-expiring-oauth-access-tokens-for-gitlab)**", GitLab explains:

> ### How do you handle expiring tokens?
>
> Once a token has expired, your API requests will fail and you will be
> prompted by GitLab to generate a new token.
>
> To do this, you must make another request to GitLab’s OAuth endpoint.
> Much like the initial link, you must provide your application’s Client
> ID and Client Secret, but instead of passing the linking code, you
> will pass in the user’s refresh token.
> **This will invalidate both the existing access token (if it is still valid) and the refresh token you just used**, and return a *new*
> access token *and* refresh token.
>
> The access token will be valid for another two hours.   You will need
> to store the new refresh token, as this token will be used the next
> time you request a new token.

Comment: but, my question was. what If after 2 hours I don't use the refresh_token to get new access_token. If I use the refresh_token after 2 weeks or so. I am unable to get new access_token

Comment: @TarunAluguri [Issue 340848](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/340848#note_953496566) mentions: "The `expires_in` value when initially getting an access token indicates how long it's valid for. The refresh token can be used anytime during or after that period of time to refresh the token."